# Multiple "if" condition for R-Shiny Calculator App

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny

I want to create an R-shiny application that calculates creatinine clearance.
According to the formula below, the calculation necessitates many "if" conditions:

[image]

In addition, I'd like to show the results of the dose adjustment depending on the creatinine clearance data.

The following is the code I'm attempting to create. Still, I'm having difficulty displaying the final results table that includes the creatinine clearance calculations (based on gender and serum creatinine conditions) and how to show antibiotic dose adjustments based on creatinine clearance results.

```
library(shiny)

# USER INTERFACE
ui <- fluidPage(
                        # Give the page a title
                        titlePanel("Kalkulator CCT"),
                        helpText("Aplikasi ini menghitung creatinine clearance berdasarkan rumus CKD-EPI dan ditambahkan dengan penyesuaian dosis antibiotik "),
                        # left input 
                        sidebarPanel(
                                     
                                     
                                     radioButtons(inputId = "sex", label = "sex", choices = c("Male", "female"), inline = TRUE),
                                     
                                     
                                     numericInput(inputId = "age", label = "Age (years)", value = 18, min = 0, max = 100, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
                                     uiOutput("age"),                         
                                     numericInput(inputId = "cre", label = "Serum creatinine (mg/dL", value = 0.89, min = 0, max = 10, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
                                     uiOutput("cre"),
                                     checkboxGroupInput("ab", "Type of antibiotics:",
                                                        c("Meropenem" = "mer",
                                                          "Levofloxacin" = "lev"
                                                         )),
                                     helpText("choose the antibiotics")
                                     
                                     ),
                        # right outputs
                        mainPanel(br(),
                                  # h3("Results"),
                                  br(),
                                  dataTableOutput("results"), width=6 ))
    )
)




# SERVER function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    # Evaluate Design Effect for selected options, and output table with values
    results.data.table <- reactive({
        
        if(input$sex=="Male")
        {
            m1 <- input$cre >= 0.9
            m2 <- input$cre < 0.9
            CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/m1)^-0.411*(0.993^input$age))
            CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/m2)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
            mer1 <- #if checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT >50 show text "0.5-1 g IV q8hr" in finalresults antibiotics
            mer2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 26-50 show "0.5-1 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            mer3 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 10-25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            mer4 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT <25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            lev1 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 20-49 show "750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics 
            lev2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 10-19 show "500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics 
                
                
        }
        
        else if (input$sex == "Female")
        {
            f1 <- input$cre >= 0.7
            f2 <- input$cre < 0.7
            CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/f1)^-0.329*(0.993^input$age))
            CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/f2)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
            mer2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 26-50 show "0.5-1 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            mer3 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 10-25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            mer4 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT <25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
            lev1 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 20-49 show "750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics 
            lev2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 10-19 show "500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics 
                
        }
        
        row.names<-c("CCT")
        
        finalresult<-data.frame("Result"=row.names, "Value"= CCT, "Antibiotics" = AB)
        
    })
    
    
    # Output data table results without any data table options (page no., row number, etc..)
    output$results <- renderDataTable({results.data.table()}, options = list(lengthChange= F, paging = F, searching = F, ordering= F, info=F))
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your have overlapping groups and missing groups.  For example, if `checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 10-25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"` and `checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT <25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"`; here if CCT is 24 what should be shown?.  Also, what should be shown if `checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT <10 or >50`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started.  Please note that you may need to adjust somethings for the issues noted in my comments.

```
library(shiny)

# USER INTERFACE
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Kalkulator CCT"),
  helpText("Aplikasi ini menghitung creatinine clearance berdasarkan rumus CKD-EPI dan ditambahkan dengan penyesuaian dosis antibiotik "),
  # left input 
  sidebarPanel(
    
    radioButtons(inputId = "sex", label = "sex", choices = c("Male", "Female"), inline = TRUE),
    
    numericInput(inputId = "age", label = "Age (years)", value = 18, min = 0, max = 100, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
    uiOutput("age"),                         
    numericInput(inputId = "cre", label = "Serum creatinine (mg/dL", value = 0.89, min = 0, max = 10, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
    uiOutput("cre"),
    checkboxGroupInput("ab", "Type of antibiotics:",
                       c("Meropenem" = "mer",
                         "Levofloxacin" = "lev"
                       )),
    helpText("choose the antibiotics")
    
  ),
  # right outputs
  mainPanel(br(),
            # h3("Results"),
            br(),
            dataTableOutput("results"), width=6 )
)


# SERVER function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mm <- c("0.5-1 g IV q8hr","0.5-1 g IV q12hr","0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr","0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr")
  lv <- c("750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day","500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"," ")
  fm <- c(" ","0.5-1 g IV q12hr","0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr","0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr")
  
  ### Evaluate Design Effect for selected options, and output table with values
  results.data.table <- reactive({
    req(input$ab)
    mer <- "mer" %in% input$ab
    lev <- "lev" %in% input$ab

    if(input$sex=="Male")
    {
      if (input$cre >= 0.9) {CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/0.9)^-0.411*(0.993^input$age))
      }else CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/0.9)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
      
      if (mer & lev) {showtext <- mm[(CCT>50)*1 + (CCT<=50 & CCT>25)*2 + (CCT>10 & CCT<=25)*3 + (CCT<=10)*4]
      }else if (mer) {showtext <- mm[(CCT>50)*1 + (CCT<=50 & CCT>25)*2 + (CCT>10 & CCT<=25)*3 + (CCT<=10)*4]
      }else if (lev) {showtext <- lv[(CCT>=20 & CCT<50)*1 + (CCT>=10 & CCT<20)*2 + (CCT<10 | CCT>=50)*3] 
      }else showtext <- ""
      
      # m1 <- input$cre >= 0.9
      # m2 <- input$cre < 0.9
      # CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/m1)^-0.411*(0.993^input$age))
      # CCT<-round(141*(input$cre/m2)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
      # mer1 <- #if checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT >50 show text "0.5-1 g IV q8hr" in finalresults antibiotics
      #   mer2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 26-50 show "0.5-1 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   mer3 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 10-25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   mer4 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT <25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   lev1 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 20-49 show "750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   lev2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 10-19 show "500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics

    }

    else if (input$sex == "Female")
    {
      if (input$cre >= 0.7) {CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/0.7)^-0.329*(0.993^input$age))
      }else CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/0.7)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
      
      
      if (mer & lev) {showtext <- fm[(CCT>50)*1 + (CCT<=50 & CCT>25)*2 + (CCT>10 & CCT<=25)*3 + (CCT<=10)*4]  ## what to show if both antibiotics are selected? - may need update
      }else if (mer) {showtext <- fm[(CCT>50)*1 + (CCT<=50 & CCT>25)*2 + (CCT>10 & CCT<=25)*3 + (CCT<=10)*4]
      }else if (lev) {showtext <- lv[(CCT>=20 & CCT<50)*1 + (CCT>=10 & CCT<20)*2 + (CCT<10 | CCT>=50)*3] 
      }else showtext <- ""
      
      # f1 <- input$cre >= 0.7
      # f2 <- input$cre < 0.7
      # CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/f1)^-0.329*(0.993^input$age))
      # CCT<-round(144*(input$cre/f2)^-1.209*(0.993^input$age))
      # mer2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 26-50 show "0.5-1 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   mer3 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT 10-25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   mer4 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is meropenem and CCT <25 show "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   lev1 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 20-49 show "750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics
      #   lev2 <- #if  checkboxGroupInput is levofloxacin and CCT 10-19 show "500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"    in finalresults antibiotics

    }
    AB <- input$ab
    row.names<-c("CCT")

    finalresult<-data.frame("Result"=row.names, "Value"= CCT, "Antibiotics" = AB, "Showtext" = showtext)

  })

  # Output data table results without any data table options (page no., row number, etc..)
  output$results <- renderDataTable({ results.data.table()}, options = list(lengthChange= F, paging = F, searching = F, ordering= F, info=F))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! your solutions taught me a lot about Rshiny.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there are two places where multiple `if` conditions need to be evaluated:

1. In choosing the proper values for the parameters `A`, `B`, and `C` for calculating `CCT` depending on `input$sex` and `input$cer`
2. In choosing the proper `text` to display depending on `input$ab` and `CCT`

Both cases can be resolved using a *lookup table* and a *rolling join*:

For the first case we need a *backward rolling join* because there is a *less or equal* (`<=`) condition on `input$cer` (*Scr* in the screenshot). So, with the lookup table

```
library(data.table)
cct_lut <- fread("
sex     cre  A    B    C
Female  0.7  144  0.7  -0.329
Female  Inf  144  0.7  -1.209
Male    0.9  141  0.9  -0.411
Male    Inf  141  0.9  -1.209
")
```

the backward rolling join picks the correct parameter values, e.g.,

```
cct_lut[.("Female", 1.0), on = .(sex, cre), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>       sex cre   A   B      C
> 1: Female   1 144 0.7 -1.209
> ```

```
cct_lut[.("Male", 0.5), on = .(sex, cre), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>     sex cre   A   B      C
> 1: Male 0.5 141 0.9 -0.411
> ```

also in case of hitting a breakpoint, e.g.,

```
cct_lut[.("Female", 0.7), on = .(sex, cre), roll = -Inf]
```

> ```
>       sex cre   A   B      C
> 1: Female 0.7 144 0.7 -0.329
> ```

For convenience this can be packed in a function which computes the `CCT` values depending on `input$sex`, `input$cer`, and `input$age`:

```
cct <- function(sex, cre, age) {
  library(data.table)
  cct_lut <- fread("
Sex     Cre  A    B    C
Female  0.7  144  0.7  -0.329
Female  Inf  144  0.7  -1.209
Male    0.9  141  0.9  -0.411
Male    Inf  141  0.9  -1.209
")
  cct_lut[.(sex, cre), on = c("Sex", "Cre"), roll = -Inf, round(A * (cre/B)^C * 0.993^age)]
}
```

The second case can be handled likewise

```
ab_text <- function(ab, cct) {
  library(data.table)
  ab_lut <- fread('
AB             CCT   text
Meropenem      51    "0.5-1 g IV q8hr"
Meropenem      26    "0.5-1 g IV q12hr"
Meropenem      10    "0.25-0.5 g IV q12hr"
Meropenem      -Inf  "0.25-0.5 g IV q24hr"
Levofloxacin   50    "NOT RECOMMENDED"
Levofloxacin   20    "750 mg initially, then 500 mg every other day"
Levofloxacin   10    "500 mg initially, then 250 mg every other day"
Levofloxacin   -Inf  "NOT RECOMMENDED"
')
  ab_lut[.(ab, cct), on = c("AB", "CCT"), roll = Inf, paste(AB, text, sep = ": ")]
}
```

The lookup table can be extended to include other types of  antibiotics as well. Note that the full range of `CCT` values need to be specified. For *Levofloxacin*, I have added the text "NOT RECOMMENDED" for those intervals which were not covered by OP's specification.

Now, the reactive expression in the server part becomes

```
  results.data.table <- reactive({
    
    CCT <- cct(input$sex, input$cre, input$age)
    finalresult<-data.frame(Result = "CCT", Value = CCT, Antibiotics = ab_text(input$ab, CCT))
    
  })
```

Note that there are no `if` constructs anymore.

Below is a screenshot of the refactored app (see complete code below):

[image]

#### Complete code of app

I have finetuned OP's code also in some other places, so here is the full code for the sake of reproducibility:

```
library(shiny)

# USER INTERFACE
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Give the page a title
  titlePanel("Kalkulator CCT"),
  helpText("Aplikasi ini menghitung creatinine clearance berdasarkan rumus CKD-EPI dan ditambahkan dengan penyesuaian dosis antibiotik "),
  # left input 
  sidebarPanel(
    
    
    radioButtons(inputId = "sex", label = "Sex", choices = c("Male", "Female"), inline = TRUE),
    
    
    numericInput(inputId = "age", label = "Age (years)", value = 18, min = 0, max = 100, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
    uiOutput("age"),                         
    numericInput(inputId = "cre", label = "Serum creatinine (mg/dL", value = 0.89, min = 0, max = 10, width=validateCssUnit("50%")),
    uiOutput("cre"),
    radioButtons("ab", "Type of antibiotics:",
                       c("Meropenem",
                         "Levofloxacin"
                       )),
    helpText("Choose the antibiotics")
    
  ),
  # right outputs
  mainPanel(br(),
            # h3("Results"),
            br(),
            dataTableOutput("results"), width=6 )
)





# SERVER function

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  # Evaluate Design Effect for selected options, and output table with values
  results.data.table <- reactive({
    
    CCT <- cct(input$sex, input$cre, input$age)
    finalresult<-data.frame(Result = "CCT", Value = CCT, Antibiotics = ab_text(input$ab, CCT))
    
  })
  
  
  # Output data table results without any data table options (page no., row number, etc..)
  output$results <- renderDataTable({results.data.table()}, options = list(lengthChange= F, paging = F, searching = F, ordering= F, info=F))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! your solutions taught me a lot about R shiny.